# Print specific HTML

Tags: html, printing

Is it possible to output markup for the printer that is not actually embedded on the page?

The issue is that I have a Flash app which renders dynamic data from a backend in such a way that isn't really print friendly, but the client wants to have a printable version as well with raw data. I can easily output such content with a simple PHP page query, but the problem is getting this to be sent to the printer when the user invokes printing.

Is the only option to create a custom print button and require the user to click that (instead of their browser print function), then load the PHP page in a new window and print that page? Or can I effectively override the HTML content that gets sent to the printer in the same way I can override the CSS with the media attribute?

Comment: Javascript has a window.onbeforeprint event. I have never used it myself but it may be worth a look.

Comment: I did come across that, however it seems to be IE only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML document sent to the printer *must* be the same one that is sent to the browser. A special print layout, as you suggest, is one common way of implementing this behavior.

Another might be to take the CSS media attribute idea and run with it: render the raw data in the original HTML document, hide it in the screen stylesheet, and show it in the print stylesheet. However, since it sounds like most of the navigation in this app occurs within the SWF and not on the browser's location bar (I'm still not totally sure I get the question), this may not be feasible. Perhaps the Flash file could send the raw data to the Javascript on the page to format it into the hidden HTML, but this might be a bit too much work to be worth the feature, and users might not even realize that they're meant to just print that page. I know I wouldn't be expecting that to just magically happen.

A print-me page might be your best option at this point. The Javascript+CSS solution might work, but it's probably not worth your time.

Comment: "Perhaps the Flash file could send the raw data to the Javascript on the page to format it into the hidden HTML"

Actually, that sounds very clean and should work. The data source is already formatted for Flash as XML which closely resembles HTML, and actually includes literal HTML for textual content, so as long as I can resolve the alternate layouts on the same page (minimalized print layout vs Flash app layout) then it should be easy to display the data in HTML on that page. I'll give this a shot!

Comment: "users might not even realize that they're meant to just print that page. I know I wouldn't be expecting that to just magically happen."

Interesting, so are you saying you wouldn't expect File>Print or Ctrl+P to be meaningful if the page was full Flash? Is that because of your experience with Flash sites in general, or some other indicatation to you from my question? And by "print-me" page you mean a button in the site that says "Print this page" or similar, which spawns a new window with printable content?

Comment: @Aaron: That's pretty much it. I know that most websites don't usually go out of their way to make Flash interfaces printable, so I'd need to be specifically told that it should work. Of course, that might just be me. And to the second question, that's what I mean :)

Comment: @Aaron: also, since this often comes up with first-time question-askers, I'll put this reminder in early: please click the check mark next to this answer if it ends up answering your question :) That marks this question as answered for everyone else's reference, gives me reputation points for a good answer, and gives you reputation points for remembering to accept an answer when done :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip (and the answer!), I'll be testing this in the next day or so and will try to remember to report back the results.

Comment: Just a follow up as promised: using Javascript to set the contents of a hidden div which is show in print worked great! Didn't have any issues with any browsers, except some of them didn't seem to like CDATA tags which I used heavily in the XML -- it was easy enough to strip those out. The rest of the XML could be styled just like normal HTML, and as long as I used img tags to represent media they even print as much you'd expect them too.

Answer (score 0):

I would possibly use the [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/content) property together with the [`:before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3abefore) pseudo-element.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="justForPrint"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#justForPrint {
    display: none
}

@media print {
    #justForPrint {
        display: block
    }
    #justForPrint:before {
        content: "test data, test data, test data, test data, test data, test data, test data, test data, test data, test data, test data"
    }
}
```

Comment: Re-read the rest of the question. I don't think this actually matches the situation :/

Comment: @Matchu: It seems relevant to me. He can output the "raw data" in an inline stylesheet. The hidden `justForPrint div` will hold the content, and it will only be visible when the page is printed.

Comment: Hm, maybe I'm just misinterpreting. It sounds to me like his issue is that he has a Flash application, and wants to, when the user hits the browser's Print button, send HTML other than the original document based on the state of the SWF and the data that the SWF asynchronously downloaded. If that's the case, then an inline stylesheet has the same issue: that specific data isn't available when the server initially sends the HTML to the client, so can't be a part of the orignial document. The issue isn't that he doesn't want that markup in the standard DOM; it can't actually be outputted then.

Comment: @Matchu: I'm not sure either. If what you're saying is the case, he can instead fire a JavaScript function from Flash to update the `content` property whenever required. I agree that a "print me" page would be easier to implement (and probably clearer to users - most users *expect* a special "Print View" page).

Comment: Yes the problem is that there is only one HTML page which asynchronously downloads and renders various data via SWF; it's not really feasible to embed all data in the page, especially considering dynamic combinations and other modifications to its rendered state that happen clientside.

However if I understand the idea of feeding the current data via Javascript correctly, I think that will work. So I assume that means modification to the DOM via Javascript will be sent to the printer as modified?

Comment: I'd have to try my idea to be certain it would work. For example, different browsers might handle the Print process differently (some might consider it a "new page", so the changed `content` property would not be there anymore). I see you're giving Matchu's idea (+1) a try, I hope it works for you :)